# How to customize the open graph object description position in the news feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

On the news feed, where the image is rendered at 200x200, I'd like the description to appear on the right and not below the image.

Here is what I have:

[image]

The description is long and gets clipped in that small one-line space. That's why I'd like it to be on the right side of the image.

This is how I configure the render, but it only seems to configure the appearance in the user wall, not in the news feed of other's wall:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you do anything special to get FB to format your post like this, with a 200x200 image and title/description underneath? One of my FB apps is formatting it like this, and another is formatting with a small image and text to the right. I'm trying to figure out how to ensure they always look like yours. Any idea?

Comment: No, I don't think I did anything special. Are you sure you are publishing as an open graph action in both apps? You know you only get small images when publishing with FB.ui('feed',...)

Comment: Yeah, I'm positive they're both posting as OG actions. Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157165/defining-how-an-open-graph-post-is-displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Facebook does not currently support displaying the description to the right of large image format stories.

If the description needs to be featured more prominently you will need to reduce the size of the image to below 200x200 to force Facebook to use the standard story format.